# RF 433 Dongle for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, pyserial

I purchased 
[this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/433Mhz-CC1101-USB-Wireless-RF-Transceiver-Module-10mW-USB-UART-MAX232-RS232-TOP-/182100149130?hash=item2a6603c38a:g:35YAAOSw6btXQ~Yx)
  RF 433 USB Dongles off Ebay and am trying to set it up to work with my pi so I can listen to a RF 433 Door Sensor.  The dongle shows up as under:

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
```

I tried sniffing for any signals coming out of the usb port using usbmon but I do not see anything coming in.

I have also tried using SerialPy but no luck.

```
ser = serial.Serial(sys.argv[1], 9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=2, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
ser.open()
while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        ser.flushInput()
        print ser.readline()
```

I see mentions of this device around the web but am not able to find a solution:

[Pimation](https://pimation.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/compatible-usb-433-92-mhz-transceivers-for-the-raspberry-pi/)

[Yesyes.info](http://www.yesyes.info/index.php/electronics/rf1100-232-rf-433mhz-transceiver-module/)